# Creating a thread dump on OpenVMS

Tags: java, thread-dump, openvms

How can I retrieve a thread dump from a running Java process on OpenVMS? The process is not JMX-enabled. I am looking for something similar to `kill -QUIT` on Unix or `Ctrl+Break` on Windows.

EDIT: I found my answer here:
http://h18012.www1.hp.com/java/documentation/1.6.0/ivms/docs/user_guide.html#javaenable_sigquit_mailbox

Comment: Would you mind posting a brief summary answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Exerpret from [open vms user guide](http://h18012.www1.hp.com/java/documentation/1.6.0/ivms/docs/user_guide.html#javaenable_sigquit_mailbox)

- **define JAVA$ENABLE_SIGQUIT_CTRLC true** : This will enable terminal programs to receive QUIT signal and dump trace to terminal
- **define JAVA$ENABLE_SIGQUIT_MAILBOX true** : This will enable non terminal programs to dump trace to mailbox created by the JVM